# Spark gives error(Initial Job has not been accepted)

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, apache-spark-sql

I am trying spark on amazon EC2 but i am facing this issue.
When i tried to run with local spark worker it works fine but when i tried with only EC2 instance it give error of Initial Job has been not accepted.
How I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

This error aises when your all resources are either held by another Job or the spark cluster has not enough resources to run your application. Try to tune the resources and check the configuration from Spark UI.

Comment: I am actually struggling with ec2 instance .Its resources are not being used by My Spark Application .Can you guide me on how to allocate resources?

Comment: When you see your spark UI what do you see can you paste your Configuration! or the screenshot